# Joint asymptotic convergence/normality of partitioned sums

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Define $S = \{1,\dots, |S|\}$, and for each $s \in S$ let $\{X_{i,s}\}_{i=1}^\infty \overset{iid}{\sim} P_s$ and assume that $E[X_{i,s}] = 0$ for each $s$.

Now, for each $n$, define $n_s(n) \leq n$ with $n_s(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{n_s(n)}{n} \xrightarrow{P} \delta_s \in (0,1)$ with $\sum_{s\in S}n_s(n) = n$ and $\sum_{s\in S}\delta_s = 1$. Let $n_s(n)$ be non-decreasing for each $n$.

Now, I want to know whether
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{n_1(n)}X_{i,1}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n_{|S|}(n)}X_{i,|S|}
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \Sigma)~,
\end{align*}
for some covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Assume that $\{X_{i,s}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ independent of $\{X_{i,s'}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ for any $s'\neq s$.

I think I can show that each of the coordinate sums is asymptotically normal, as follows:

Fix some $s$ and define $X_i = X_{i,s}$. Now, let $Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$,
and now the CLT gives that, for some $\sigma_s$,
$$Z_n \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma_s)~,$$
and so
$$E[I\{Z_n \leq x\}]=P(Z_n \leq x) \rightarrow \Phi_s(x)~,$$
where $\Phi_s(x)$ is the cdf of $N(0, \sigma_s)$.

Now, since $\frac{n_s(n)}{n} \xrightarrow{P} \delta_s$, we get the necessary result (by continuous mapping thm) if we can show that $E[E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)]] = E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}] \rightarrow \Phi(x)$.

So, by the Vitali convergence theorem, we are done if we can show that $E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)] \xrightarrow{P} \Phi(x)$.

Finally,let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and note that there exists $N$ such that $|P(Z_n \leq x) - \Phi(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n > N$. Now, we have that we can pick $n$ sufficiently large so that $P(n_s(n) \leq N) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and so, for sufficiently large $n$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(|E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)] - \Phi_s(x)| > \epsilon) =&\ P(|E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)] - \Phi_s(x)| > \epsilon| n_s(n) > N)P(n_s(n) > N) + P(|E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)] - \Phi_s(x)| > \epsilon| n_s(n) \leq N)P(n_s(n) \leq N)\\
\leq&\ P(|E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)] - \Phi_s(x)| > \epsilon| n_s(n) > N)+P(n_s(n) \leq N)\\
<&\ \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}~,
\end{align*}
and so, $E[I\{Z_{n_s(n)}\leq x\}| n_s(n)] \xrightarrow{P} \Phi(x)$, as required.

I think this correct, but I am not sure how to to go from this to joint convergence. I think it should be possible to use the above result to say something like
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{n_1(n)}X_{i,1}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n_{|S|}(n)}X_{i,|S|}
\end{pmatrix}|\{n_1(n), \dots, n_s(n)\} \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \Sigma_2)~,
\end{align*}
where $\Sigma_2$ is the limit of some conditional covariance matrix? Or something like that? But I am not sure how to get there formally

Comment: Are your $n_s$ deterministic ?

Comment: No, not necessarily